# Complex slightly-nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to make a somewhat-complex somewhat-nest form.  What I have (simplified) is the following:

models/product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :colors
end
```

models/color.rb

```
class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :quantity
  belongs_to :product
end
```

views/admin/update_inventories.html.erb

```
<% @products.each do |p| %>
  <%= p.name %>
  <% p.colors.each do |c| %>
    <%= c.name %>: 
    <%= form_for :color, :url => color_update_path(:id => v.id) do |f| %> 
      <%= f.number_field :quantity, :value => c.quantity, :min => 0 %> 
      <%= submit_tag "Update" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The problem with that is it creates a frightning amount of forms and you have to update one suit by one suit.  What I want is something like this view:

view/admin/update_inventories_revised.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :inventory, :url => custom_update_path do |f| %>
  <% @products.each do |p| %>
    <%= p.name %>
    <% p.colors.each do |c| %>
      <%= f.number_field :quantity, :value => c.quantity, :min => 0 %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <% f.submit_tag "Update All" %>
<% end %>
```

But I can't seem to figure out to controller side logic to match it.  What do I need to do controller side to make that view (or something with the same effect) function?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) in you model.

When you get that setup, all you will need to do is `product = Product.create!(params[:product])`  The nested objects will get save automatically, assuming the nested forms were built right.

If you need help building the nested forms, check out the `fields_for` help at [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) link.